# Submit form button requires two clicks on mobile if virtual keyboard is currently displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form. On mobile Chrome, when I am on one of the text fields for the form, the virtual keyboard shows up. Then, I tap on the submit button (with the virtual keyboard still on) and this first tap will only hide the virtual keyboard, but not trigger the button's action. I will have to tap a second time, once the keyboard is hidden, in order to submit the form.

This does not happen on other platforms or mobile browsers, like Safari or Firefox for Android. On these, taping on the submit button even with the virtual keyboard up, the form will be submitted directly.

Does anybody know of a way to perform two actions with one click of a submit form button?

First: Simulate some kind of action or directly make the virtual screen go away.

Second: Submit the form

```
    <form id="SelectForm"  method="post"/>  

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Restaurant Name</legend>
            <div class="text"> 
                <label>Starts with: </label>
                  <input type="text" title="Enter starting letters of 
name." name="f_name_strt_ds" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="All"/>
            </div>
    </fieldset>



<script>
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('SelectForm').action = action;
        document.getElementById('SelectForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

'''

To see this, use chrome on mobile android.  Go to www.searchpv.com.  Click Search, click Restaurants, Enter an 'a' in the "starts with" field.  Page to the bottom (keeping the keyboard displayed).  Press the "List Restaurants" button.  It will first hide the keyboard, then will have to be pressed again to submit the form.

Comment: i guess this is chome's natural behaviour - by hitting "return" with the virtual keyboard the form should also be submitted

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?